# How to set values of y axis in react-chartjs-2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I can't find any documentation on how to change the y axis values from the default ones. The data im plugging into the chart can have any value from 0-150. However, the y-axis starts at 84 and ends at 98. Here's the link to it's npm page.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2

Answer (score 0):

I would say that what you need is this:

```
const options = {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
        }
      }],
    }     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default y axis tick values by adding the following option.

```
const options = {
scales: {      
  y: {
    beginAtZero: true,
    ticks: {
            //displays only 6 ticks on y axis at specific distance
            maxTicksLimit: 6,
           
            callback: (val, index) => {
            
            //will show ticks for y-axis that lies between 0-150
            return  (Number(val)>=0 && Number(val)<=150 )? val : "" ; 
           
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** If it still displays the y-axis form 84 to 98, you should also consider checking -

- The complete data is getting passed to chart data
- The passed data's data type (Number | String) should be of type number